# How to set an initial sort order on a personal parser in jQuery tablesorter?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have made a custom parser in [jQuery Tablesorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com). I want to have the table to be sorted on 3 columns with that custom parser when you load the page.

I have tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#statusTable").tablesorter({ sortList: [[3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 0]]}, { headers: { 3: { sorter: 'status' }, 4: { sorter: 'status' },
            5: { sorter: 'status' }, 0: { sorter: false }, 7: { sorter: false} }});
    });
</script>
```

The columns are sorted when the page is loaded but they are sorted alphabetically.

Another script I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#statusTable").tablesorter({ headers: { 1: { sorter: 'status' }, 2: { sorter: 'status' },
        3:{ sorter: 'status'}, 5:{ sorter: false}}}, { sortList: [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]] }); });
</script>
```

But then the columns aren't sorted at all.

Last script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#statusTable").tablesorter({ sortList: [[3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 0]], headers: { 3: { sorter: 'status' }, 4: { sorter: 'status' },
            5: { sorter: 'status' }}, { headers: { 3: { sorter: 'status' }, 4: { sorter: 'status' },
            5: { sorter: 'status' }, 0: { sorter: false }, 7: { sorter: false} }});
    });
</script>
```

But then the tablesorter didn't work anymore.

**Does anyone have any suggestions?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a little brace-happy on your JSON. Have you tried just cleaning up your code, and maybe using indenting to see where you're at with syntax?

Here's your first version cleaned up:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#statusTable").tablesorter({ 
          sortList: [[3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 0]]},
          headers: {
            3: { sorter: 'status' }, 
            4: { sorter: 'status' },
            5: { sorter: 'status' }, 
            0: { sorter: false }, 
            7: { sorter: false } 
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm going on the assumption that your first was best (along the same premise as going with your first instinct on a test). You were wrapping `headers` in braces unnecessarily (and, in-fact, never closed it).

Comment: That didn't make a difference cause I did closed my braces properly. What happened was that the columns were ordered indeed, but they were ordered alphabetically and not using my cutom parser. Also the headers weren't used anymore.
(it has to be {headers: {...}} instead of headers: {...})